# Docker mysql connection error

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

I have my app running on container. I have mysql server started and having trouble to connect my app with mysql server. [This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODMGM.png) of the error

my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=new_password
      - MYSQL_USER=composetest
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=new_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sample_db
      - MYSQL_HOST=localhost

  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python check_db.py --service-name mysql --ip db --port 3306 &&
                      python manage.py migrate &&
                      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: Could you provide the Docker-compose file?

Comment: ya i have uploaded my docker-compose.yml file

Comment: My last answer should not be the reason, sorry. To get deeper, maybe it will be needed the piece of source where you make the connection.

Comment: It's intriguing the error description as looks like it is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, are you sure the hostname and port are reaching propperly to the connection configuration? Maybe there is a "localhost" hardcoded somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to link the web container to the db container.

Add the following to the web configuration and it should be all:

```
links:
   - db
```

Answer (score 0):

I would love to write my docker-compose  as bellow.
No need to set **host** and should link the service with **depends_on**

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=new_password
      - MYSQL_USER=composetest
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=new_password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=sample_db

  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I have removed  the commands from the docker-compose which you  can add to the bash script and add to run it at entrypoint. The script will look something like  bellow. I am doing cd to go the respective directory  where the applications is installed.

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

#getting into the directory where the command should run.
cd /app

python check_db.py --service-name mysql --ip db --port 3306
python manage.py migrate 
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

> In the database setting part where you set the hostname put the
>   service name in your case its **db** .
>
> These  is in overall what I do in laravel app  deploy  must be similar
>   in your case too